random letters after resizing with varables
When I use the resize function, it doesn't do it right. It should add 211210999999788789 at the end, but it doesn't. There are just some random õ letter.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
I tried changing aa to a string, but it gave me an error, saying that you can't insert a string into the resize function.
Keyn is a user input. Outputn is the Output.
int nine(999999);
unsigned long long aa;
unsigned long long keyn;
string outputn;

aa = nine * keyn;
                
outputn.resize(80, aa);
std::cout << outputn;

I expected this outcome:

460886096095635214735862262257526448155944944896789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789211210999999788789

and so on.
But I got this:

460886096095635214735862262257526448155944944896789õõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõõ

and so on.

Doesn't the compiler complain that you pass a unsigned long long to a function that expects a char?

And std::cin >> keyn << endl;? Please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre].

Why should it add 211210999999788789 to the end when you tell it to make it 80 chars long (with 80 - outputn.size() number of static_cast<char>(aa)s appended if the string isn't already 80 characters or longer).

the String should be 1000 characters long. 80 was my fault. sorry.

@Someprogrammerdude no it doesnt

@LuganWolf You can edit the question to make it into a [mre], but it doesn't matter if it's 80 or 1000. You tell it to make outputn X characters long and fill it up with static_cast<char>(aa)s if needed. It will make X - outputn.size() copies of static_cast<char>(aa) to fill outputn up to the wanted size.

Are you expecting outputn.resize(80, aa); to "stringify" aa, and effectively do outputn += std::to_string(aa); until the size is 80?

The value for the variable aa is not initialized.  Could be anything.  Code is invalid.  The value for keyn is not initialized.  The value for aa depends on the value of keyn.

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Did you want outputn.resize(1000, '9');?  The second parameter is a single fill character:  std::string::resize()

@ThomasMatthews keyn is user input

There is no input before keyn is used in a calculation.

@thomasmatthews i know that there isnt one in this codesnippet. But my question is why i can put a variable into the resize function

@LuganWolf You can put a variable into the resize function as you've clearly done. It just doesn't do what you expect, but what I've described.  Please read std::string::resize

@TedLyngmo ok thanks. Do you gave any idea to put a variable x amount of times behind a string or an unsigned long long?

@LuganWolf auto as_str = std::to_string(aa); for(i = 0; i < x; ++i) outputn += as_str; would be one way
